# Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information in c#

Tags: ads, bing-ads-api

We have implemented Bing ads API using this link "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/code-example-keyword-planner?view=bingads-13".

Now, For the last few days, we have been getting issues like:

> "Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information."

For below lines of code:

```
var getKeywordIdeaCategoriesResponse = await AdInsightExampleHelper.GetKeywordIdeaCategoriesAsync();
```

Can anyone please guide me for which reason we are getting this issue?